# Shiny app: force an image to have the same width than the Sidebar panel

Tags: image, shiny

I'm a Shiny newbie, and I have a very simple question, though I didn't find the answer on Google: I want to put an image in my Sidebar Panel, and I want the width of the image to be the same than the Sidebar Panel.

The problem is, when the user changes the side of the window in which they display the shiny app, the Sidebar Panel width changes automatically, whereas the image's width remains the same...

Is there a function such as sideparPanel.width that I could use to fit my image to the sidebar panel ?

My code below, in which the image has a fixed width of 500 pixels:

```
 library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #the title panel (mandatory)
  titlePanel("title"),

  sidebarLayout(
  #The sidebar panel (default position = left)
      sidebarPanel(
      img(src="myimage.png",width=500)
    ),

    #Content of the main panel
    mainPanel("blablabla"
    )
  )

))
```

Thank you very much for you help !

Comment: You can try the `absolutePanel` which enforces absolute positioning of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify width as a percentage instead of pixels. For example,

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  #the title panel (mandatory)
  titlePanel("title"),

  sidebarLayout(
  #The sidebar panel (default position = left)
      sidebarPanel(
      img(src="myimage.png",width="100%")
    ),

    #Content of the main panel
    mainPanel("blablabla"
    )
  )
))
```

In this case, the width of the image is always relative to that of the sidebar.

Comment: Please indicate whether or not these answers resolve your problem